# Excluindo registros marcados com checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, checkbox

Queria poder excluir vários registros de uma tabela apenas selecionando os registros usando o `checkbox`, igual o Gmail, eu seleciono os e-mails que quero excluir ou marcar como lido. Pois quando preciso excluir algum registro ainda tenho que ficar excluindo um de cada vez.

Sou muito leigo em `JS`, até que eu consegui mostrar em um alert o array com os ids que o usuário selecionou, mas não sei como executar uma instrução sql para excluir os registros marcados, a ideia seria excluir assim que o usuário clicar em "OK" dentro do alert.

Andei pesquisando na internet mas ainda fiquei com duvidas, alguns exemplos usavam ajax.

**Código de exemplo**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function coletaDados() {
        var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('editar');
        coletaIDs(ids);
    }

    function coletaIDs(dados) {
        var array_dados = dados;
        var newArray = [];
        for (var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++) {
            if (typeof array_dados[x] == 'object') {
                if (array_dados[x].checked) {
                    newArray.push(array_dados[x].id)
                }
            }
        }
        if (newArray.length <= 0) {
            alert("Selecione um pelo menos 1 item!");
        } else {
            alert("Clique em OK para confirmar a exlusão do(s) registro(s) : [ " + newArray + " ]");
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
// Variáveis declaradas somente para ilustrar o exemplo

$id1 = "1";
$id2 = "2";
$id3 = "3";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tabela de Exemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="10%">
            <tr>
                <td>Registros</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="editar" id="<?php echo "$id1"; ?>"> A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="editar" id="<?php echo "$id2"; ?>"> B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="editar" id="<?php echo "$id3"; ?>"> C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button onclick="coletaDados()" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%">Excluir</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Queres apagar sem carregar a página ou ao enviar um formulário que carrega a página?

Comment: Queia apagar sem carregar a página

Comment: Sem recarregar é necessário Ajax, e uma pagina de php especifica para interpretar o pedido Ajax e eliminar os dados

Comment: e se fosse pra enviar para uma outra pagina? algo sem ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código envia por ajax os id's que você quer apagar:

> Ver comentários

```
function coletaDados() {
    var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('editar');
    coletaIDs(ids);
}

function coletaIDs(dados) {
    var array_dados = dados;
    var newArray = [];
    for (var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++) {
        if (typeof array_dados[x] == 'object') {
            if (array_dados[x].checked) {
                newArray.push(array_dados[x].id)
            }
        }
    }
    if (newArray.length <= 0) {
        alert("Selecione um pelo menos 1 item!");
    } else {
      var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

      ajax.open("POST", "nomeDaPagina.php", true); //definir o nome do arquivo que recebe os dados via POST.
      ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


      ajax.send('ids=' + newArray);

      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {

          var data = ajax.responseText;
          // seu código para apagar os ids da página
          alert(data); // retorno da página PHP.
        }
      }
    }
}
```

A página PHP que vai processar os ID's para apagar os registros deve estar esperando o parâmetro `ids` pelo método POST conforme abaixo:

```
$ids = $_POST['ids'];
```

Se estiver utilizando PDO pode fazer o delete dessa forma:

```
$ids = $_POST['ids'];
require_once('db.php'); //chama seu arquivo de conexão com o banco de dados

$exclui = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM suaTabela WHERE id in ( :ids )");
$exclui->bindValue(":ids", $ids);
$exclui->execute();
echo "ID's apagados: ". $ids; //retorno que será enviado para o alert.
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso!